# How to get a substring between the third and fourth separating character in a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an API to create some images.  When I make the HTTP request, I am returned a string like so:

```
{"img": "?svg=mscfP39TT", "errors": [],"naturalWidth": 199.671,"actualWidth": 199.671}
```

If I append `?svg=mscfP39TT` to the site's URL, it shows the image.  In order to get this substring I am currently doing this:

```
NSArray *splitStrings = [imgLoc componentsSeparatedByString:@"\""];
NSString *URL = [@"site.com/" stringByAppendingString:[splitStrings objectAtIndex:3]];
```

I'm curious if there is a better or more efficient way to do this without involving an array?  I know that I just want that one substring, the rest is useless to me. Is there any way to just substring the string from say the third `"` to the fourth?

I am having trouble phrasing what I'm looking for, so sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Please read up on common web-based data transfer formats. You should recognize JSON, XML, Base64-encoded data, URL percent escaping, etc. if you seriously mean to interact with any web back-end.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? Sure it's a beginners question in a way. There is nothing wrong with that. Technically it is not a duplicate - even though there are a lot questions of this kind. And OP showed much more effort than at least half of the questions we meet here. I upvoted it not because I believe it deserves an upvote - it's not that good - but to anulate the unfair downvote. And H2CO3 gave a good advice (not only for the OP) on base of this question.

Comment: @rokjarc [You're doing it wrong.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74666/is-voting-to-balance-in-the-spirit-of-the-site)

Comment: @H2CO3: i know it is wrong from many points of view - but not from all of them. Actually Grace Note (OP of accepted answer from your link) said: "As long as the voter is backing that vote, I'm fine with it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hacking and making assumptions about the exact string you get back, you should parse it using the `NSJSONSerialization` class, since it seems valid JSON.

```
NSData *strData = [stringResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:strData options:kNilOptions error:NULL];
NSString *query = [dict objectForKey:@"img"];
NSString *urlStr = [@"site.com/" stringByAppendingString:query];
```

Comment: I hastily threw this code together a few weeks ago, and just noticed it.  I should have back-tracked more, the help page on the site for using the API even tells me that it returns JSON.  Embarrassing.  Thank you for your help.